# Semantically marking up a page to fit visual design

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

Am trying to decide the best way to markup this design I'm working on. The quick outline of it is here:

[image: page layout wireframe]

It's a news article.. so I'd like to use the article tag and then some aside information. My issue is the design layout of it.. the h1 of the article spans over the 2 columns.. I want to use article tag for the h1, publish information and main body.. but in order to do that and fit the design I'd have to include the rightcolumn inside the article which is not great semantically. The information in the right column is common to lots of pages so shouldn't be part of an aside.

So at the moment I'm thinking along the lines of

```
<h1>News article title</h1>
<div class="leftcol">
    <article>
    <p>publish information</p>
    <p>Main body in general markup</p>
 </article>
<aside>
Related content here
</aside>
</div> <!-- end left col -->
<div class="rightcolumn">
Contact form code, followed by customer quote stuff
</div> <!-- end right column -->
```

I'm concerned about leaving the H1 outside the article tag - Seems like it kind of defeats the purpose, but I'm not sure what other way would work. Possible repeat of the h1 tag inside the article as well but that's definitely not ideal..

What is the most semantically correct way of marking this design up?

***ED**

Can't do opinion based questions.. but in case anyone else is considering the same thing (and not allowed to ask it) I went with the following:

```
<div class="page-heading">News article title</div>
<div class="leftcol">
<article>
    <h1>News article title</h1>
    <p>publish information</p>
     <p>Main body in general markup</p>
</article>
<aside>
    Related content here
</aside>
</div> <!-- end left col -->
<div class="rightcolumn">
    Contact form code, followed by customer quote stuff
</div> <!-- end right column -->
```

Decided to keep the h1 within the article (and hide it with css) and then just use a div outside the columns with the same content to hold true to the design.

Comment: Wasn't opinion based at all after the edit, but they seem to have marked it and forgotten about it.

Comment: In any case: the header MUST be within article because it's a semantic unit. You don't need to duplicate header, just use JS to get it from the DOM. Apart from that: the header really belongs to the article block semantically, so why not visually too?! is there a pressing requirement to show it full page length?! Just a thought.